# Inject list of beans using yaml configuration

Tags: spring, yaml

I got some interface for example "BeanInterface" and multiple Spring Beans which implement this interface e.g BeanA, BeanB. In other class I got list of this beans: `List<BeanInterface>`. And what I'm trying to do is inject to `List<BeanInterface>` only Beans which are specified in yaml configuration.

To do that I specified in yaml, list of beans names which I want to inject.

```
app:
    beans:
        - BeanA
        - BeanB
```

Result is -

```
Property: app.beans[0]
    Value: 
    Origin: class path resource [application-local.yaml]:86:6
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.myprojects.BeanInterface]
```

Properties BeanA, BeanB are only String values, so how can I specify bean names?

Comment: why are you trying to inject some beans via yaml configuration dynamically? Dont you only need to inject all beans to List<BeanInterface> that implement BeanInterface?

Comment: I want to configure which beans should be injected to list.

Comment: okay but should it be dynamically configured from external configuration?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Only at start of the application spring should get configuration from yaml file, which beans should inject to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be injecting beans to the list on the application start, then retrieve that bean to use later. Show me an example using BeanFactory to get beans and add them to a list:

Configuration class that injects beans to the list by their given name from application.yaml:

```
@Configuration
public class DynamicBeanInjection
{
    @Value( "${app.beans}" )
    private String[] beans;

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    List<DynamicInterface> getDynamicBeans( )
    {
        final List<DynamicInterface> dynamicInterfaces = new ArrayList<>( );
        for ( String bean : beans )
        {
            dynamicInterfaces.add( beanFactory.getBean( bean, DynamicInterface.class ) );
        }
        return dynamicInterfaces;
    }
}
```

Create a DynamicInterface and its 3 implementations:

```
public interface DynamicInterface
{
}

@Component("FirstDynamic")
public class FirstDynamic implements DynamicInterface
{
}

@Component("SecondDynamic")
public class SecondDynamic implements DynamicInterface
{
}

@Component("ThirdDynamic")
public class ThirdDynamic implements DynamicInterface
{
}
```

application.yaml

```
app:
  beans: FirstDynamic, SecondDynamic
```

And here is the sample output from the example:

> Injected bean size: 2